# Jython syntax error

Tags: python, jython

I am getting syntax error in my code.
Can anyone say whats wrong in the syntax?

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  (no code object) at line 0
  File "<string>", line 867
            if (file.endsWith(".ear") || file.endsWith(".war")):
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My code:

```
for file in [ears for ears in os.listdir(warPath)]:
  if (file.endsWith(".ear") || file.endsWith(".war")):
    file_list.append(file)
```

I have a warpath where there are multiple war ,ear and sql files.
my below condition should read all the files and if condition should filter only war and ear files and store it in a file_list.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `||` where you meant to use `or`:

```
if file.endswith(".ear") or file.endswith(".war"):
```

Note that the `str.endswidth()` method name is *all lowercase*.

Jython supports at least Python 2.5, so you can just use a tuple:

```
if file.endswith((".ear", ".war")):
```

See the [Jython string methods documentation](http://www.jython.org/docs/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods):

> `str.endswith(suffix[, start[, end]])`
>
> Return `True` if the string ends with the specified *suffix*, otherwise return `False`. *suffix* can also be a tuple of suffixes to look for. With optional *start*, test beginning at that position. With optional *end*, stop comparing at that position.
>
> Changed in version 2.5: Accept tuples as *suffix*.

Your `for` loop looks overly complicated; no need to loop over `os.listdir()` in a list comprehension:

```
for file in os.listdir(warPath):
    if file.endswith((".ear", ".war")):
        file_list.append(file)
```

but if you can use a list comprehension there then you probably are using a Jython 2.7 beta, so you may as well make the `file_list` definition a list comprehension:

```
file_list = [f for f ir os.listdir(warPath) if file.endswidth(('.ear', '.war'))]
```

If you are using an older Jython version (such as 2.1, as bundled with Websphere 8), you cannot use either a tuple argument to `str.endswith()` nor list comprehensions. You'll have to append still:

```
for fname in os.listdir(warPath):
    if fname.endswith(".ear") or fname.endswith(".war"):
        file_list.append(fname)
```

I've used `fname` here instead of `file`, which is a built-in name in Python. Best not mask it.

Comment: hi,
Thanks for your quick response.

I am getting below error when i used 
 if file.endswith((".ear", ".war")):

Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<string>", line 867, in ?
TypeError: 1st arg can't be coerced to string

Comment: @User050488: looking at the [Jython PyString source](http://hg.python.org/jython/file/5688f9c2b743/src/org/python/core/PyString.java#l3253) tuples are definitely supported. What version of Jython is this?

Comment: @User050488: Jython 2.5 [also supports it](http://hg.python.org/jython/file/5ce837b1a1d8/src/org/python/core/PyString.java#l2050), and the error message doesn't match. The [2.7 error message](http://hg.python.org/jython/file/5688f9c2b743/src/org/python/core/PyString.java#l754) also doesn't match your exception. Not sure what is throwing the exception here, but I cannot see what source line threw that in your traceback.

Comment: hi , i am writing this for websphere 8 ,i am not getting what is the supporting jython version for websphere 8

Comment: @User050488: see https://wiki.python.org/jython/WebSphere, you have Jython 2.1. I'll adjust.

Comment: Thanks for the info.provide me the code for the same.